# Combine two SELECT queries with different function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table for reports. My first select query is that combines all sales tables

```
SELECT *, ds_sales.id_sales
FROM ds_sales LEFT JOIN
     ds_payment 
     ON ds_sales.id_sales=ds_payment.id_sales LEFT JOIN 
     customer_info
     ON ds_payment.id_customer=customer_info.id_customer INNER JOIN
     ds_salesdetails
     ON ds_salesdetails.id_sales=ds_sales.id_sales
WHERE customer_info.id_customer = '".$_POST["id_customer"]."'
```

This is the result of the query

[image: This is the result of the query]

and my second query is this, to filter the same sales serial number, since the ds_salesdetails table have many sales serial number

```
select ds_salesdetails.id_sales, count(*),
       group_concat(ds_salesdetails.id_product)
from ds_salesdetails
having count(*) >= 1
```

I need to merge them to create a report for customers sales.

Comment: Code seams prone to SQL injections..  Besides [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY id_sales` in the second query. There's no need for `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1` -- if the count is 0, it's not in the table so there's nothing to return.

Comment: Did you mean `HAVING COUNT(*) >= some higher number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with the grouped subquery instead of the whole table.

```
SELECT *, ds_sales.id_sales
FROM ds_sales LEFT JOIN
     ds_payment 
     ON ds_sales.id_sales=ds_payment.id_sales LEFT JOIN 
     customer_info
     ON ds_payment.id_customer=customer_info.id_customer LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT id_sales, count(*) as product_count,
           group_concat(ds_salesdetails.id_product) AS product_list
    from ds_salesdetails
    GROUP BY id_sales) AS grouped ON grouped.id_sales = ds_sales.id_sales
WHERE customer_info.id_customer = '".$_POST["id_customer"]."'
```

Comment: The output stills duplicate the serial number. :(

Comment: I misunderstood the question. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! It works well in greater than 1 id_sales in table ds_salesdetails, but it doesnt displaying less than 1 id_sales. Ive checked the operator, its already >=. :(

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` if you want rows with no sales.

Comment: Thank you again! It works well in console in my PhpMyAdmin, but in my php code, i doesnt, seems like the error is in my code in php.

Comment: Try converting to prepared statements. That will protect you from SQL injection and also often solves other syntax problems.